# DLL implementation & cannot make static reference error

Tags: java, linked-list, computer-science

hi im getting an error message " cannot make static reference to non-static field "

in the bold lines for the next code and i dont know how to fix it and is my implementation correct for the linked list knowing that i want it to be a doubly linked list

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.lang.Number;
public class chainLadder {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

    public   LinkedList<Object> readData() {
         LinkedList<Object> listData = new LinkedList();

         Integer cost=0;
        
        System.out.println("how many years are you calculating");
            int numY=s.nextInt();
while(numY!=0) {    
    
 
     int i =1;
         System.out.println("please Enter the year"+i+" to calculate from ");
             String year = s.next();
                     listData.add(year);
                     listData.add(">"); // what comes after is the cost and before is the year

                     System.out.println("enter the costs of year"+year+"/n  enter ( -1 ) when done ");

                     while(cost != -1) {
                         cost = s.nextInt();
                         if(cost == -1)
                             break;
                         listData.add(cost);
                         System.out.println("next");
}
                     listData.add("<"); // what comes before is the cost and after  is the year


   numY--;// going down till we finish all the years
   i++;
  

}//end of while
    return listData;
    }//end method readData
    
    
}//end class
```

Comment: Please take your time and format the code properly so it is readable for normal people.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you get an error, you should include the line that gets flagged by the compiler as containing the error :) - just a tip.

Your problem is that 'static' is a bit of an exotic concept, at least relative to the first few weeks of learning java. I suggest you avoid it. Do so by using this as skeleton:

```
class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MyApp().go();
    }

    void go() throws Exception {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

give the `go` method the `String[] args` param if you need the command line parameters. Then, don't make anything static, other than `main` which must be.

static is certainly useful, but perhaps not a concept that's particularly worthwhile to start your java learning with, and if you don't understand it it's just going to cause endless confusion.

If you insist on not making this change, you have to call the `readData` method on an isntance of `chainLadder`, so: `new chainLadder().readData();`, not `chainLadder.readData();`.

Having a 'heterogenenous' list (a list that contains different concepts; yours contains both year values as well as costs as separate objects) is very unjava-like.

You should either make a class that represents a year/cost pair and make it a `List<YearInfo>` or whatnot, or more likely you want a map that maps years to costs, so, a `Map<Integer, Integer>`.

You're using an existing linked list impl and not writing your own. If you need a doubly linked list because the homework assignment requires it, then the point is for you to write the entire implementation yourself, and not to use `java.util.LinkedList` at all so that you learn how linked lists work. No real life requirement ever goes 'it .. MUST .. be a doubly linked list!'. Given that only a few thousand years are relevant for humans, your list will never contain enough items. Therefore, `ArrayList` is the right answer even if it seems algorithmically unsound. That is, if you want a list at all - most likely `Map` is what you're looking for if this isn't a homework exercise.